# "You which know the secret of my heart"?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to say *"You which know the secret of my heart"*?
If yes, what is the difference from *"You who know .... "* ?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not correct to say "you which know". Your second sentence, "you who know", is OK, but clumsy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. How could I express the sentence : "You WHO know the secrets of my heart, give me a shining smile, one more time" in a better way? It's a song... Thanks!

Comment: In a song, it's OK. But nobody talks like that. Normally relative clauses do not modify pronouns -- relative clauses are to identify nouns, and pronouns are for nouns that are already identified.

Comment: you THAT now? better or not than you WHO know?

Answer (score 0):

Adding *which* makes "You which know the secret of my heart" a sentence fragment.

This would be the proper way of writing it:

> You, which know the secret of my heart, *verb* blah blah.

Note the added commas.  Also, using "which" instead of "who" is archaic.  That's probably a quote from the King James Bible.

Comment: Hello, RonJohn. I'd be as happy using 'You who know the secret of my heart ....' as 'You, who know the secret of my heart, ....' The commaed version is clearly non-restrictive, the commaless version arguably restrictive (you, a subset of those people who know the secret of my heart, ....) But a flowery, archaic example. // The 'which' for 'who' would be unacceptable in modern writing not aiming at a historical flavour. Your penultimate sentence answers the question. Can you add a link to an (attributed) supporting reference covering the change (or at least a couple of examples)?